# What does the .mvn folder inside Spring Boot project mean?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, wrapper

What is the **.mvn** folder in the root level of a **spring boot** project used for?

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ IDE's project sidebar]

and what does the **wrapper** folder mean? And its contents
`maven-warpper.jar`, `maven-wrapper.properties`, `MavenWrapperDownloader.java` also `mvnw` in root project folder, `mvnw.cmd`.

Answer (score 7):

They are Maven Wrapper.

- https://github.com/apache/maven-wrapper

> Why might this be necessary? Maven to date has been very stable for users, is available on most systems or is easy to procure: but with many of the recent changes in Maven it will be easier for users to have a fully encapsulated build setup provided by the project. With the Maven Wrapper this is very easy to do and it's a great idea borrowed from Gradle.